# Form not showing on Show(), because it's being used(?)

Tags: c#, forms, docking

I'm having trouble trying to remove a Form from this [Dock Container](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25976/Visual-Studio-IDE-like-Dock-Container) once I used the `dockContainer.Add(form)` and later the `dockContainer.Remove(dockableFormInfo)` and when I make it show itself using `form.Show()`, it wont show up at all.

Looking trough the properties it shows that the form is actually `visible = true`, but even though the dockable control that uses the Form was removed from the Container, my thoughts are that it still used the Form resources and thus I am unable to make it appear outside the control.

How can I make the Form show up?

Comment: can you show your current code..?

Comment: Surely the dock container is tinkering with the Form properties to force it into the container.  With high odds for the TopLevel property.  When set to false, the Show() method isn't going to make it visible if the form doesn't have a Parent.  Best to just create a new instance of it.

Comment: Consider calling Form.Hide after you remove it from the dock container

Comment: The correct project page is: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42800/Visual-Studio-IDE-like-Dock-Container-Second-Versi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, first thanks to Hans Passant for the TopLevel tip.

After removing from the docking container, just set **TopLevel to true**!

Here is the test code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Crom.Controls.Docking;

namespace DockingTester
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Form dummyForm;
        private readonly Guid dummyFormGuid = Guid.NewGuid();


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CreateDummyForm();
            this.dummyForm.Show();
        }

        private void CreateDummyForm()
        {
            dummyForm = new Form();
            this.dummyForm.Text = "Dummy docking test form";
        }

        private static void DockUndockForm(DockContainer dockContainer, Form form, Guid guid)
        {
            DockableFormInfo formInfo = dockContainer.GetFormInfo(guid);

            //Add
            if (formInfo == null)
            {
                formInfo = dockContainer.Add(form, zAllowedDock.All, guid);
                dockContainer.DockForm(formInfo, DockStyle.Left, zDockMode.Inner);
            }
            //Remove
            else
            {
                Form dummy =  formInfo.DockableForm;
                dockContainer.Undock(formInfo, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, new Size(100, 300)));
                dockContainer.Remove(formInfo);

                dummy.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
                dummy.TopLevel = true;
            }
        }

        private void dockUndockButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.dummyForm.IsDisposed)
                CreateDummyForm();
            DockUndockForm(this.dockContainer1, this.dummyForm, this.dummyFormGuid);
        }

    }
}
```